# C++ When saving data into another file, only the last line is written into new file, when instead I need the whole data to be written

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, io, output

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string nname;
    cout << "Enter new name for file" << endl; // prompts user to enter new filename
    cin >> nname;
    fstream myFile;
    myFile.open("example.txt", ios::in); //opens the data folder loaded
    if (myFile.is_open()){ 
        cout << "Is open now" << endl << endl; 
        string text;
        while(getline(myFile, text,'\n')) //reads the string line from text
        {
            cout << text << endl;
            ofstream outfile(nname);
            outfile << text;
            
            outfile.close();
        }
      
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

"example.txt" being:

```
5
Id,Age,math,science,malay
2
1201101128,20,30,12,30
1201101127,33,44,66,11
```

The new file only has the "1201101127,33,44,66,11" line and does not contain the other lines.
I've read that the "while" loop is making it so that it reads all of the lines one-by-one, but only outputs the last one. My question is, how do you make it so that it outputs all of the lines?

Comment: Why give delimiter `\n` in `getline`?

Comment: You're opening and thus truncating the file in a loop.

Comment: I actually took the code from a website, couldn't remember which one. It had the \n by default so I didn't change it. Would it be better if I didn't have it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file in the `while` loop each time. Open the file before the loop and close it after the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string nname;
    cout << "Enter new name for file" << endl; // prompts user to enter new filename
    cin >> nname;
    fstream myFile;
    myFile.open("example.txt", ios::in); //opens the data folder loaded
    if (myFile.is_open()) { 
        cout << "Is open now" << endl << endl; 
        string text;
        ofstream outfile(nname);
        while (getline(myFile, text)) //reads the string line from text
        {
            cout << text << endl;
            outfile << text << endl;
        }
        outfile.close();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: damn, thanks for letting me know! I've been stuck on this for the past few hours hahahah

Comment: If my answer was useful, do consider upvoting it :-)